# aws cli: aws kms encrypt/decrypt using powershell

Tags: powershell, aws-cli, amazon-kms

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt content with the aws cli on powershell (not the powershell specific one but [the standard one](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html))

### Here is my way to do it and that seems closer to the truth:

```cs
$input = "foo"
$file_path = "$(pwd)\file"
$region = "eu-west-1"

# ENCRYPT
$ciphertextblob =
   aws kms encrypt `
     --region $region `
     --key-id "a266be0d-304b-4gf2-8b75-021ba4b0d23a" `
     --plaintext $input |
   ConvertFrom-Json |
   Foreach-Object { $_.CiphertextBlob }

$encrypted = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ciphertextblob)
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($file_path, $encrypted)

# DECRYPT
$decrypt =
   aws kms decrypt `
     --region $region `
     --ciphertext-blob "fileb://$file_path"

# SHOW
$decrypt
```

and the result is

```json
{
    "Plaintext": "Zm9v",
    "KeyId": "arn:aws:kms:eu-west-1:639530368848:key/a266be0d-304b-4gf2-8b75-021ba4b0d23a"
}
```

### As you can see:

- I define an input "foo" that becomes "Zm9v" at the end
- "Zm9v" is not base64
- I take the encrypt command result, transform from JSON to Powershell object then take the CiphertextBlob
- I decode that from base64 to plaintext and write it in a binary file with WriteAllBytes
- finally I use the fileb to read the binary file with the decrypt command

### So my problem seems:

that I must have a missing encoding somewhere ... if someone could help me progress :-D

Regards,
Thibault

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was to thought $decrypt to not be base64.

Here is the full working example:

```cs
$input = "foo"
$file_path = "$(pwd)\file"
$region = "eu-west-1"

# ENCRYPT
$ciphertextblob =
   aws kms encrypt `
     --region $region `
     --key-id "a266be0d-304b-4gf2-8b75-021ba4b0d23a" `
     --plaintext $input |
   ConvertFrom-Json |
   Foreach-Object { $_.CiphertextBlob }

$encrypted = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($ciphertextblob)
[io.file]::WriteAllBytes($file_path, $encrypted)

# DECRYPT
$decrypt_base64 =
   aws kms decrypt `
     --region $region `
     --ciphertext-blob "fileb://$file_path" |
   ConvertFrom-Json |
   %{ $_.Plaintext }

$decrypt_plaintext = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString(
   [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($decrypt_base64)
)

# SHOW
$decrypt_plaintext
```

And the result as expected is:

```
foo
```